# Stock price prediction, choosing amount of time in the future using scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use machine learning to predict stock prices. I'm having issues choosing how long out to predict, I want to be able to predict out 100-200 days in the future. It seems like my code is cutting off the last 200 days and adding it's prediction there, instead of adding a additional 200 days of the prediction. For example if I have 1000 days of data I want the 1000 and the 200 0f the prediction, right now it's cutting off the last 200 and making it's prediction there instead. To make my question easier to understand, say I have a data set with integers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, how do I tell the predict method I want the next 2, 10 or 20 integers in the series? I'm just starting out following a tutorial, and doing a bad job of it, it kind of just says put this here and that there, not much insight on what everything is doing. Not sure if LinearRegression is the best way to do it, would be happy with any insight you can provide, Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import math`enter code here`
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

df = pd.read_csv('spyqqqq.csv')

df = df[['Open','High','Low','Adj Close','Volume']]

df['label'] = df['Adj Close'].shift(-200)

df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = np.array(df.drop(['label'],1))

y = np.array(df['label'])

X = preprocessing.scale(X)

X_lately = X[:-200]

X_train, X_text, y_train, y_text =  cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.1)

clf = LinearRegression()

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

accuracy = clf.score(X_text,y_text)

forcast = clf.predict(X_lately)

print("accuracy ",accuracy)
print("forcast ",forcast)

plt.plot(forcast,linestyle='solid',ms=0,color='blue')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think it's a one of those rights-of-passage into machine learning where people think they can predict the stock market. If you could do it independently, then you'd be in the Bahamas, if you can do better than average, you'll be in a company with an NDA to not spread the word, and well, the rest of us are here to throw money into the system.

Comment: lol I know what your saying, I'm just trying to be able make a prediction at this point not even thinking of the accuracy. It's one thing to be able to swing a bat, another to be able to hit a 99 mph fastball, I'm just looking to be able to swing the bat at this point.

Comment: @roganjosh To make my question easier to understand, say I have a data set with integers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, how do I tell the predict method I want the next 2, 10 or 20 integers in the series?

Comment: @phillyphil linear regression is only going to output a single number. If you want the prediction for 2 times steps ahead, then you train a model for that if you want one for 10 time steps ahead than you'll need to train a separate model to do that (by running `df['label'] = df['Adj Close'].shift(-n)` where `n=10` i.e. `n` is the number of timesteps ahead you want to predict). So if you wanted predictions for each of the next 10 timesteps using linear regression, you will need to fit 10 separate models. Needless to say, linear regression is a poor tool for this task.